# How to shift marked lines downwards in a document in BASH?

Tags: bash, line

I have a document marked like this, with a "q" marking the start of a group of text:

```
q What animals live in the forest?
Rabbits.
Fish and crocodiles.
Bears and llamas.
q What animals live in the desert?
Cats.
Rhinos and deer.
q What animals live in the sky?
Flying fish.
Birds and eagles.
```

I need to add some spaces between each, such that everything is shifted downwards. The first line starting with "q" is sent to the 10th row, the second line starting with "q" to the 20th row, and the third to the 30th row, etc. The other lines are simply pushed down, but stay with their group of text. This is difficult to do manually, as I have many such entries in many such formatted files.

Sample output:

```
q What animals live in the forest?
Rabbits.
Fish and crocodiles.
Bears and llamas.





q What animals live in the desert?
Cats.
Rhinos and deer.






q What animals live in the sky?
Flying fish.
Birds and eagles.
```

Is there a solution using BASH tools to achieve this?

Comment: Yes a script. Nothing will do it "out of the box", you have to script it. Bash, Perl, Python, ...   Twice the same question?  or very close.  A script to do one can be adapted to do the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '2,$s/^q /\n\n\n\n\n\nq /'
```

What `sed` does: For every line between the second line (`2`) and end of file (`,$`), if a line starts with `q` (`s/^q`), substitute the single `q` with 5 newlines and a `q` (`/\n\n\n\n\n\nq/`).